# Can we use Agave sweetener & hard Apple Cider

Tags: cider

Can we use Agave sweetener to backsweeten hard apple cider?

Comment: Why not? What are you concerned about?

Answer (score 2):

Yes but this is still a fermentable sugar so the cider will need to be heat pasteurized or chemically preserved for a long shelf life or cellar aging.

If it will be consumed soon usually keeping it refridgerated is sufficient to prevent further fermentation.